# Why isn't my image changing when I mouse over it?

Tags: css, hover

Here is my HTML.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .button {
                background: url('images/1.png');
            }

            .button:hover {
                background: url('images/2.jpg');
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="button" src="images/1.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

The files are present but it still doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard method is CSS:

```
input.mybutton { background-image: url('button.jpeg'); }
input.mybutton:hover { background-image: url('selectedButton.jpeg'); }
```

Using JavaScript, you can overwrite the .src of an image:

```
imageElement.src = 'selectedButton.jpeg';
```

Comment: This isn't working. Can you please give a working example? Where do I put input.mybutton? :S

Comment: @Sergio Tapia: Take a look at the example here http://www.kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/pure-css-image-hover/

Comment: The first code sample I posted was CSS, not JavaScript. So input.mybutton is CSS code, referring to an <input class="mybutton" ...> Take a look at R0MANARMY's link, it explains everything.

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="button.jpeg" onmouseover="this.src='selectedButton.jpeg'" onmouseout="this.src='button.jpeg'"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I copied exactly as you did, renaming my pictures as I have them. No dice.

Comment: looks okay.. may be you are doing something wrong, check again.. PS. css method is more standard way to do a mouse hover effect

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is to use css and set the background image of the element based on the hover property.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery in your application then it will be fairly simple.On mouseover event of the button just swap the background image.Following sample code does it for a div element :-

```
<div class="title"/>

 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('div.title').mouseover(function () {
                $(this).css("background-image", "url('Forest Flowers.jpg')");
            });
        });
```

Comment: Why bother? This can be done with simple, very simple javascript and css

Answer (score 1):

Use `a` tag to wrap the image.

```
<hmtl>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        a.button{
            background: url('images/1.png');
                            display:block;
                            width: *width*;
                            height: *height*;
        }

        a.button:hover{
            background: url('images/2.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<a class="button"></a>
</body>
```

**Edit:** I just realize that you are trying to replace the background image under your image....

one option that you have is to use javascript. but if you want to use only CSS and alse want to use this image as control, the above edited solution is good.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript to do this. Use **[onmouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onmouseover)** and **[onmouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.onmouseout)** events to handle this.

If you can use jQuery then you can use the hover event.

```
$("img.button").hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("src","path of image on mouse over");
},
function(){
    $(this).attr("src","path of image on mouse out");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used an h1 tag. I have tested the following code in IE8,Firefox,GoogleChrome and it is working, we just need to add the doctype correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.button {
    background: url('images/1.jpg');
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}

.button:hover {
    background: url('images/2.jpg');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="button"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Images don't generally have background images. Use a different element, and non-relative paths would probably be a good idea, too.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons do not have a hover state. You might want to try A (link) tags, and set the background there.

Comment: guess you wanted to be down-voted. Care to prove your theory that img tags have a hover css state?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes "CSS does not define which elements may be in the above states, or how the states are entered and left." Pretty much any DOM element can have a hover state.

Comment: Guess you wanted to argue about something you have no experience with.

Comment: fine, fine...gotta hand it to you. Though there are ways to say things man. If you were going to correct me (which I'm all for), just include a reference. thanks for the link and the info.